# magento 2.2.6 Indexer:reindex error

Tags: database, magento2.2.6

I get the following error when running the indexer:reindex command for Magento 2.2.6

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DB.catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica' doesn't exist, 

query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica`
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: You have missing table "catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica" in your database.

Comment: did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing a table. Run this Query directly in your MySQL Database and try it again:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica` (
  `category_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Category Id',
  `product_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Position',
  `is_parent` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Parent',
  `store_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `visibility` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Visibility'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Category Product Index Store1 Replica';
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'DB.catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica' doesn't exist
Open new phpMyAdmin window